# Invalid identifier in dynamic select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I  have a little procedure which should truncate partition if exists

```
create or replace PROCEDURE                 drop_partition(p_table_name VARCHAR2, p_load_seq INTEGER)
AS
        l_sql_text         VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR);
        l_part_exists      NUMBER;
BEGIN
        l_sql_text:= 'SELECT count(*) FROM  user_tab_partitions where table_name=' || p_table_name ||' and high_value='||p_load_seq ;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_text INTO l_part_exists;
        if (l_part_exists=1) THEN
        l_sql_text := 'ALTER TABLE ' || p_table_name || ' DROP PARTITION FOR(' || to_char(p_load_seq) || ')';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_text;
        END IF;
END;
```

If I try to run procedure like this

```
call drop_partition('test',1);
```

There is an error:

```
ORA-00904: "TEST": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "DROP_PARTITION", line 8
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the table name in single quotes, which you'll need to escape:

```
... where table_name=''' || p_table_name ||''' and ...
```

i.e.:

```
l_sql_text:= 'SELECT count(*) FROM  user_tab_partitions where table_name=''' || p_table_name ||''' and high_value='||p_load_seq ;
```

There is an [alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) that removes the need to escape the quotes but I think it would be more confusing here.

When using dynamic SQL it can be useful to output the generated statement for debugging purposes, before executing it:

```
dbms_output.put_line(l_sql_text);
```

and enabling output in your client before you make the call.

---

As Justin Cave quite rightly pointed out, the query part of your procedure doesn't need to be dynamic anyway; you can use static SQL:

```
SELECT count(*)
INTO l_part_exists
FROM user_tab_partitions
where table_name = p_table_name
and high_value = p_load_seq;
```

---

Identifiers like table names are uppercase in the data dictionary by default, so you could do `upper(p_table_name)` in that statement (static or dynamic); but in case you do have any mixed-case quoted identifiers you could instead rely on the caller passing the name in the correct case:

```
drop_partition('TEST', 1);
```

... assuming your `test` table doesn't have a quoted identifier.

Comment: Could  you please  add a little about the alternative mechanism that you referred to?

Comment: @СтаниславКитаев - added a link to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) that explains it.

Comment: I'd just add that there is no need to use dynamic SQL for the query against `user_tab_partition`.  Just use static SQL and you don't have to worry about making mistakes building up SQL statements at runtime (or SQL injection attacks).